# Use SBT tags to control specs2 test concurrency

Tags: concurrency, sbt, specs2

I want to control the concurrency of some of my specs using SBT tags.

For example, I don't want more than 1 test that uses the database to run at the same time.

With ScalaTest, I would do

```
@TagAnnotation("database")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface DatabaseTest { }

@DatabaseTest
class MyDatabaseTest1 ...

@DatabaseTest
class MyDatabaseTest2 ...
```

and then in build.sbt,

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global += exclusiveGroups(Tag("database"))
```

Most tests to be executed in parallel, but `MyDatabaseTest1` and `MyDatabaseTest2` would not run at the same time as the other.

Can I do this with specs2?

Comment: Did you try to annotate your specification with the same tags? I actually was not aware that you could reduce the level of concurrence of specifications using this. Note that each specification stays concurrent unless you use the `sequential` argument.

Comment: @Eric, er, `TagAnnotation` is a ScalaTest annotation that is (I assume) consumed by the ScalaTest runner and exposed to SBT. I should have made that clear.

Comment: And yeah, the execution of examples within a spec is controlled by specs2, not SBT. I find that easy enough to control as all examples can be seen in one file.

Comment: Ok, I got it. This is not supported yet. One way to do this in specs2 would be to create a parent spec with links to the database specs and execute that one sequentially. The drawback is that you have to maintain this parent spec and add new specs when you have some. So the better way is for you to wait for me to implement it :-)

Comment: I have added the missing support for tags in `3.7.3-20160413201225-0d1765e` but in the form of tags that specs2 already knows about: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.7.3/org.specs2.guide.Selection.html#use-tags. I have tried to observe the "no concurrency" behaviour of sbt but couldn't see anything though (but I see that the tags are found).

Answer (score 0):

I added the functionality myself. (Issue for built-in support: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/470)

**src/test/java/test/Tag.scala**

First define an annotation to be used. (I believe this can only be done in Java.)

```
package test;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Tag {
    String name();
}
```

**src/test/scala/test/TaggingFramework.scala**

Then define an implementation of `sbt.testing.Framework` that wraps a `Framework` and adds tags for the annotations. (Note: This depends on [org.scala-sbt:test-interface](https://github.com/sbt/test-interface). If you are already pulling in specs2, it should be there already.)

```
package test

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation
import sbt.testing._
import scala.util.Try

class TaggingFramework(framework: Framework) extends Framework {
  def fingerprints(): Array[Fingerprint] = framework.fingerprints()

  def name = s"TaggingFramework(${framework.name})"

  def runner(args: Array[String], remoteArgs: Array[String], testClassLoader: ClassLoader) = {
    val runner = framework.runner(args, remoteArgs, testClassLoader)
    println(runner)
    new Runner {
      def args() = runner.args()

      def done() = runner.done()

      def remoteArgs = runner.remoteArgs()

      def tasks(taskDefs: Array[TaskDef]) = runner.tasks(taskDefs).map { task =>
        new Task {
          def execute(eventHandler: EventHandler, loggers: Array[Logger]) = task.execute(eventHandler, loggers)
          def taskDef = task.taskDef
          def tags = task.tags ++ {
            val fingerprint = taskDef.fingerprint
            Try {
              val isModule = fingerprint.getClass.getMethod("isModule").invoke(fingerprint).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
              val className = taskDef.fullyQualifiedName + (if (isModule) "$" else "")
              println(testClassLoader.loadClass(className).getAnnotationsByType(classOf[Tag]).map(_.name).toSeq)
              testClassLoader.loadClass(className).getAnnotationsByType(classOf[Tag]).map(_.name)
            }.getOrElse(Array.empty)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**project/TaggingTestFramework.scala**

Then in the build definition, define a `TaggingTestFramework` subclass of `sbt.TestFramework`. This will load the `TaggingFramework` if it is present. Otherwise, it just uses the original framework.

```
import sbt.TestFramework
import sbt.testing._
import scala.language.existentials
import scala.util.Try

class TaggingTestFramework(testFramework: TestFramework) extends TestFramework() {
  override def create(loader: ClassLoader, log: sbt.Logger) = testFramework.create(loader, log).map { framework =>
    Try(
      Class.forName("test.TaggingFramework", true, loader).asInstanceOf[Class[Framework]]
        .getConstructor(classOf[Framework]).newInstance(framework)
    ).getOrElse(framework)
  }

  override def toString = s"TaggingTestFramework($testFramework)"
}
```

**build.sbt**

And wrap the `testFrameworks`.

```
testFrameworks := testFrameworks.value.map(new TaggingTestFramework(_))
```

This should mostly work any Scala or Java framework, including specs2.

---

**src/test/scala/example/MySpec.scala**

Finally, to use add a tag to a testing task, simply add the annotation to the class.

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import test.Tag

@Tag(name = "database")
class MySpec extends Specification ...
```

---

Note 1: This currently does not work with inheritance.

Note 2: SBT forked tests work very differently. This and many other testing features are not available for forked tests.